# How do I write to a File stored in a path in Java

Tags: java, file, path

I have a Path variable like this:

```
Path output;
```

This path is initialized in the main-method.

I want to check if there exists a File in this path
and if thats the case- write a string into that file.
Else create a new File with the given path and write
the string.

```
//void parseOutput(String s){
//if (file in path exists)
//   write(s in file from path)
  else
     File f = new File(String.valueOf(output)); 
     write String in f
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can try this :

import java.io.*;
class FileDemo {
    public static void main(String str[]) {
        String path = "E:/myfile.txt";
        File file = new File(path);
        if(file.exists()) {
            System.out.println("File is exist..!!!");
        } else {
            try {
                FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(path);
                fileWriter.write("This is my first file..!!");
                fileWriter.close();
                System.out.println("File has some content..!!");
            } catch(Exception exception) {
                System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Path, it doesn't really make sense to convert that to a String and use the File constructor.

For checking if a file exists, you can use [Files exists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#exists(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...)).

To add to an existing file, have a look at [Files.newBufferedWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedWriter(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset,%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...)) with the [APPEND OpenOption](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html#APPEND) set.

Full example:

```
Path path = Paths.get("/path/to/file.txt");

try (BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = Files.newBufferedWriter(
        path, StandardOpenOption.APPEND, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
     PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(bufferedWriter))
{
    printWriter.println("This is a line");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [exists()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#exists-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.LinkOption...-) method in File class. Here's an example which you could use:

```
public void writeOnFile(String path, String str) throws FileNotFoundException {
        PrintWriter out;
        File file = new File(path);

        if (file.exists()){
            out = new PrintWriter(file.getPath());
            out.println(str);
        }
}
```